# How does Hibnerate choose property capitalization?

Tags: hibernate

```
@Entity
class Host 
{
    private String Model;
    private String OS;

    @Column (name="OS")
    public String getOS() ...

    @Column (name="MODEL")
    public String getModel()...

}
```

So when I say Restriction.eq('OS", "foo") and Restriction.eq("model", "foo") it works but not "os" or "Model" or "MODEL". So way does the capitalization get dropped for model and not OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would determine capitalization by introspecting getter methods. You can read about conventions in [Java Beans Specifications](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/spec-136004.html).

Comment: Thank you. Your are correct. I read the spec and it says that if the first two characters of the property are capitalized then the original capitalization is retained. However, if only the first character is capitalized then the first character is converted to lower case. So "getModel" becomes "model" and "getOS" retains "OS"